# Advices for IVR SDK [ based on SIP] with C#

Tags: sip, ivr

We are looking for IVR SDKs. [based on SIP ]

Anyone has any advice, for commercial- open source SDKs for IVR [ which you used it in production]

**PS:**

> I do not look for just SDK names.I can google it also. :-) I look for
>   guys who used any SDK and wanted to share their experineces.

Answer (score 1):

If "IVR SDK" means a method to develop voice/speech applications that run on an IVR platform then take a look at the open source project [VoiceModel](http://voicemodel.codeplex.com/). VoiceModel is a framework for developing voice/speech applications using C# and ASP.NET that run on any [VoiceXML](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/) compatible IVR and [Tropo](https://www.tropo.com/home.jsp).  This allows you to define your Voice User Interface (VUI) but it is not an IVR platform. For an IVR platform I would recommend using Voxeo Prophecy which has a SIP telephony interface.  VoiceModel has been tested extensively on [Voxeo Prophecy](http://voxeo.com/products/voxeo-prophecy/) and Tropo, which is a cloud based IVR solution.

Comment: I mean API which helps to develop an IVR application easily.I do not want complete IVR system. And Voice Model is based on VoiceXML and I do not want end user generate dynamic XML for each new IVR scenario using ASP.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean when you say, "I do not want a complete IVR system." but you want an IVR API. You will have to be more specific if you want any decent answers. You mentioned in your question that you do not want SDK names that you can Google yourself. A suggestion is to list examples of what you think are IVR  SDK's and have people comment on their experience. I have developed a lot of IVR applications and the closest thing to an SDK was Microsoft Speech Server, which is now part of Lync.

Comment: Well, I know UCMA framework. But It does not do conference without Lync Server.

Comment: What I mean with "complete IVR system" is , IVR product lile Voxeo Prophecy.

Answer (score 1):

For open source products, I have not found any that are stable enough to put into production status. You can try Asterisk AGI but calls will drop in volume scenarios.

Voice XML products were not powerful enough to meet our business requirements.

For a commercial products, I recommend PIKA HMP. Great platform but for .NET you would have to write interfaces to the C++ libraries but its not that hard. I have the code if anyone needs it. The SDK is synchronous calls which makes it hard to program your logic. You also have to control threading and memory management. Pretty rock solid.

Dialogic HMP is decent but you have to deal with Dialogic. Good luck trying to buy a license from one of their re-sellers. There are some .NET examples but I found the .NET interface to be buggy but that was several years ago. The more stable systems runs on Linux. You will find your self restarting the drivers often in development. Very frustrating. If using Dialogic, go Linux, C++. It supports video.

Take a look at VoiceElements they have been around for a long time and implemented a lot of large high volume systems.

AccuData HMP is very complex, no .NET interfaces, and pricey. They do support video conferencing.

PC Best Networks library looks promising. Support team is responsive.

PortSIP, Ozeki are worth a shot but I doubt they handle a high volume scenarios.